# Get data by joining table does not work in oracle

Tags: oracle, left-join

I have 2 tables where I want to join it and gets its data. For ex: Table A consists of Error Code and the description of its code is in Table B.

So the value of Error Code is stored like `,1`, `,2`, `,1,2` in table A.

`tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data`   -> Table A

`TBL_INVALID_ERROR_DATA`    ->  Table B.

I tried joining like below but the Remarks was all blank

```html
SELECT a.SPAN_ID,MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME,a.MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE,a.R4G_STATE_NAME,
a.NETWORK_CATEGORY,a.NETWORK_TYPE,a.CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY,
a.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE,a.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CODE,a.ROUTE_NAME,a.INTRACITY_LINK_ID ,
a.CALCULATED_LENGTH, REPLACE(a.REMARKS, ',1', '1') as REMARKS
  FROM tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data a
  left JOIN TBL_INVALID_ERROR_DATA t
   ON a.REMARKS = t.ID;
```

Let me know where I am wrong. and how to replace all those comma separated values

**update**

```html
Table:tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data
Name                     Null Type            
------------------------ ---- --------------- 
SPAN_ID                       NVARCHAR2(100)  
MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME         NVARCHAR2(100)  
MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE         NVARCHAR2(50)   
R4G_STATE_NAME                NVARCHAR2(50)   
STATE_NAME                    NVARCHAR2(50)   
NETWORK_CATEGORY              NVARCHAR2(100)  
NETWORK_TYPE                  NVARCHAR2(100)  
CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY      NVARCHAR2(50)   
INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE         NVARCHAR2(20)   
OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CODE           NVARCHAR2(20)   
ROUTE_NAME                    NVARCHAR2(100)  
INTRACITY_LINK_ID             NVARCHAR2(100)  
CALCULATED_LENGTH             NUMBER(38,8)    
LAST_UPDATED_BY               NVARCHAR2(100)  
LAST_UPDATED_DATE             DATE            
REMARKS                       NVARCHAR2(1000) 


Table:TBL_INVALID_ERROR_DATA

Name     Null Type           
-------- ---- -------------- 
ID            NUMBER(18,8)   
ERR_CODE      NVARCHAR2(500)
```

Sample data as followed

Table 1

[![img1][1]][1]

Sample data table 2

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: DDL of tables, sample data and expected output will help here

Comment: Code snippets are for html/css/javascript, read the edit help, use code blocks here. Look at the formatted version of your post before you post. Format code reasonably. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Ask 1 question per post.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified example that shows how you can extract integers from a comma separated list (`REMARKS` in `tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data`), and then join that to the error codes list (`TBL_INVALID_ERROR_DATA`) to get the messages:

```
WITH codes AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT SPAN_ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(remarks, '\d+', 1, level) AS code
  FROM tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(remarks, '\d+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT t1.*, t2.err_code
FROM tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data t1
JOIN codes c ON c.SPAN_ID = t1.SPAN_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_INVALID_ERROR_DATA t2 ON t2.id = c.code
ORDER BY t1.SPAN_ID
```

Output (for my simplified demo):

```
SPAN_ID     MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME   REMARKS     ERR_CODE
1           Zone 1                  ,1          Span id length too short
2           Zone 2                  ,2          Inventory suspended
3           Zone 3                  ,1,2        Span id length too short
3           Zone 3                  ,1,2        Inventory suspended
4           Zone 4                  ,2,1        Span id length too short
4           Zone 4                  ,2,1        Inventory suspended
5           Zone 5                  null        null
```

If you want all the errors for a zone in one line, you can aggregate them in a second CTE and `JOIN` to that instead:

```
WITH codes AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT SPAN_ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(remarks, '\d+', 1, level) AS code
  FROM tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(remarks, '\d+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
),
msgs AS (
  SELECT SPAN_ID, LISTAGG(err_code, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY code) AS err_codes
  FROM codes c
  LEFT JOIN TBL_INVALID_ERROR_DATA t2 ON t2.id = c.code
  GROUP BY SPAN_ID
)
SELECT t1.*, m.err_codes
FROM tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data t1
JOIN msgs m ON m.SPAN_ID = t1.SPAN_ID
ORDER BY t1.SPAN_ID
```

Output

```
SPAN_ID     MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME   REMARKS     ERR_CODES
1           Zone 1                  ,1          Span id length too short
2           Zone 2                  ,2          Inventory suspended
3           Zone 3                  ,1,2        Span id length too short, Inventory suspended
4           Zone 4                  ,2,1        Span id length too short, Inventory suspended
5           Zone 5                  null        null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=116939e19e0e106c21f4f18603173579)

Comment: hey nick, thanks for the answer.. didnt got y so duplicate entries ? not getting it

Comment: @hud I've updated the demo to make it more applicable to your question.

Comment: @hud not sure what you mean by "justify"?

Comment: @hud you need `codes` because it is the list of every error message for each row in `tbl_fiber_invalid_trans_data`.

Comment: @hud note I made a slight change to the query so it still returns rows where they have no remarks

Comment: I'm back on chat will be around occasionally during the day

Comment: @hud sorry about the lack of response - I've been on holiday. I'm glad to see you got an answer.

Comment: @hud that's a really complex procedure. Without some sample data it will be really hard to debug. Can you build a demo fiddle on dbfiddle.uk?

Comment: @hud you should add that to your question so others can see it too.

Answer (score 1):

You need a join with `LIKE` as follows:

```
ON a.REMARKS || ',' like '%,'|| t.ID || ',%';
```

### Update

You must use the following query:

```
SELECT SPAN_ID,
       MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME,
       MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE,
       R4G_STATE_NAME,
       NETWORK_CATEGORY,
       NETWORK_TYPE,
       CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY,
       INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE,
       OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CODE,
       ROUTE_NAME,
       INTRACITY_LINK_ID,
       CALCULATED_LENGTH,
       LISTAGG(ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS REMARKS,
       LISTAGG(ERR_CODE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS ERR_CODE
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT A.SPAN_ID,
       MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME,
       A.MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE,
       A.R4G_STATE_NAME,
       A.NETWORK_CATEGORY,
       A.NETWORK_TYPE,
       A.CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY,
       A.INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE,
       A.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CODE,
       A.ROUTE_NAME,
       A.INTRACITY_LINK_ID,
       A.CALCULATED_LENGTH,
       T.ID,
       T.ERR_CODE
  FROM TBL_FIBER_INVALID_TRANS_DATA A
  LEFT JOIN TBL_INVALID_ERROR_DATA T 
  ON A.REMARKS || ',' LIKE '%,' || T.ID  || ',%')
GROUP BY SPAN_ID,
       MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME,
       MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE,
       R4G_STATE_NAME,
       NETWORK_CATEGORY,
       NETWORK_TYPE,
       CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY,
       INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE,
       OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CODE,
       ROUTE_NAME,
       INTRACITY_LINK_ID,
       CALCULATED_LENGTH
```

Comment: It will give two records. You need to use the aggregation for contacting that rows